# How to observe object attribute change without observing other attribute changes in Lightning Aura?

Tags: javascript, lightning, aura

I have one component:

```
<aura:component >

    <!-- testing change event -->
    <aura:attribute name="testObj" type="Object"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initialize}"/>
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.testObj.observedAttr}" action="{!c.objAttrChangeHandler}"/>


    <ui:button label="Increment Observed" press="{!c.updateObjAttr}"/>
    <ui:button label="Update Obj" press="{!c.updateObj}"/>

</aura:component>
```

With a controller

```
({
    initialize : function(component) {
        component.set("v.testObj", { observedAttr: 1, otherAttr: -1 });
    },


    updateObjAttr : function(component, event) {
        component.set("v.testObj.observedAttr", component.get("v.testObj.observedAttr") + 1);
    },

    updateObj : function(component, event) {
        var obj = component.get("v.testObj");
        obj.otherAttr -= 1;
        component.set("v.testObj", obj);
    },


    objAttrChangeHandler : function(component, event) {
        console.log(event.getParam("value"), event.getParam("oldValue"));
    }
})
```

By reloading component, pressing button `Incremenet Observed` and then `Update Obj I get following console output:

```
Object {}, null
2, 1
Object {}, Object {}
```

I am not interested in changes of whole object as stated in `value="{!v.testObj.observedAttr}"`. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you update the top level, we fire all the change events for the children. We would have to do a deep comparison otherwise and that is deemed to expensive.

Comment: I understand, It all would be fine if the `event.getParam('value')` and `event.getParam('oldValue')` methods returned `testObj.observedAttr` value each time. Currently it returns `testObj` or `testObj.observedAttr`. The first one is unexpected and requires additional code to handle this case in event handling function.